# Mongodb execute only one query in $or condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is my $or condition

```
{
  $or: [
    { keyword: "pocket hole drill bit" },
    { price: { $in: ["03"] } },
  ];
}
```

currently it executes both the queries in array, i want to get result from only first condition, if first condition is null then get result from second condition, is there any way to achieve without making 2 calls.

sample documents -

```
{
  keyword: "pocket hole drill bit",
  price: ["010"]
}
{
  keyword: "test123",
  price: ["03"]
}
```

I want to search with the field "keyword" first, if the given keyword is not available then search by field "price".
The result should contain one document.
Similar JS code to achieve it

```
let result = docs.find((doc) => doc.keyword === 'pocket hole drill bit' || doc.price.includes("03"))
```

result will contain first document

```
   {
      keyword: "pocket hole drill bit",
      price: ["010"]
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some sample json documents and their corresponding expected output to further illustrate?

Comment: Is price stored as a number? Putting it in quotes will search as a string.

Comment: no, price is a string, not sure how will that affect the query logic

Comment: Please explain what do you want to achieve. Do you want two sets of documents returned, separated according to the condition they met? Do you want to reduce the number of times the second query is running?  We need to understand what do you want to achieve in order to help

Comment: i have added more details, hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

No, with an `$or` you query for documents that satisfy either condition. The operator accomplishes the same as the following JS, with greater efficiency of course:

```
const keywordMatchDocs = collection.filter(
  doc=>doc.keyword === "pocket hole drill bit"
);
const priceMatchDocs = collection.filter(
  doc=>["03"].includes(doc.price)
);
const matchingDocsById = new Map;
for (const doc of [...keywordMatchDocs, ...priceMatchDocs]) {
  matchingDocsById.set(doc.Id, doc);
}
const results = [...matchingDocsById.values()];
```

Comment: no, or query will return all documents that satisfy any of the conditions in an array, and i know what i need cannot be done with $or so that's why the question is asked.

Comment: You did not clarify that you wanted to accomplish this without `$or`. You have just rephrased what I said about `$or`. You cannot achieve the "early return" with `$or`.  If you hope to reduce the operations required here, you have some options:
1. If you can influence the database architecture, you could create an index for `keyword`.
2. You could query for all documents that match the `keyword` and then apply the second query on all documents whose ID's are not in the first result array. This however would require two calls, the outcome you hoped you could avoid.